# Click on Graph empties the display - but only once

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

When Dygraph loads, i am seeing the graph as expected:

[Initial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlZ67.png)

Now, when i click the graph the values all disappear. Moving the mouse also doesn't make anything show up in the legend overlay - so the values aren't out of bounds, they're gone completely.

**Edit: clickCallback also doesn't fire in this state.**

[Empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxUUF.png)

To fix this, i can zoom via the range selector. I have to zoom in, **and then zoom out again** by an arbitrary value for the graph to show back up.

This fixes the graph **completely**. Clicking doesn't make the values disappear anymore, no matter what i do. Until i reload the page of course.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

My code:

```
new Dygraph(
    this.el.id,
    data.file,
    {
        rollPeriod: 1,
        legend: 'always',
        showRoller: false,
        title: data.title,
        labelsDiv: 'dygraph-legend-'+(data.type),
        labelsSeparateLines: true,
        hideOverlayOnMouseOut: true,
        labelsShowZeroValues: false,
        xlabel: 'Wavelength (nm)',
        ylabel: '<span class="yTransmission">%T</span>',
        axisLineWidth:'4',
        strokeWidth:'2',
        axisLabelFontSize:10,
        axisLabelWidth:40,
        gridLineWidth:0.2,
        colors: data.colors.split(','),
        dateWindow: [data.start,data.stop],
        valueRange: [null, null],
    
        axes: {
            x: {
                valueFormatter: function(x) {
                    return x + ' nm';
                }
            },
        },

        showRangeSelector: true
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sharing a live example (perhaps via dygraphs.com/jsbin) makes it easier to help you debug.

But looking at your code, here are two guesses:

- Why is `valueRange` set to `[null, null]`? Can you just omit it?
- It's surprising that `axisLineWidth` and `strokeWidth` are set to strings rather than numbers. JavaScript is notoriously willing to coerce values to the expected type, and sometimes this can lead to behaviors like this, where some code paths work as expected and others don't.

Comment: Those are both good points, however they did not fix this behaviour. I cannot provide you with the live example publically, as theres sensitive data on that page. Is there a way to send it to you privately?

Comment: You can make a simplified / redacted version of the data that still exhibits the problem.